# Sending data from function to view template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a blade template that looks something like this:

```
<div class="comment">
    <div class="username"></div>
    <div class="message"></div>
    <div class="children">

    </div>
</div>
```

I need to be able to call this view from a function and insert data into it.

I have a class, `Helpers.php`, with a recursive function that looks like this:

```
function getComments(array $comments)
{
    foreach ($comments as $comment)
    {
        echo $comment;

        if (!empty($comment->children))
        {
            getComments($comment->children);
        }
    }
}
```

What this is meant to do is print out a comment, and then check if that comment has any children comments and recurse if it does.

How can I modify my view/function so that I can send data to the view, such that I end up with something like this:

```
<div class="comment">
    <div class="username">Username1</div>
    <div class="message">Hello, world!</div>
    <div class="children">
        <div class="comment">
            <div class="username">Username1</div>
            <div class="message">Hello, world!</div>
            <div class="children">
                <div class="comment">
                    <div class="username">Username1</div>
                    <div class="message">Hello, world!</div>
                    <div class="children">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="comment">
    <div class="username">Username1</div>
    <div class="message">Hello, world!</div>
    <div class="children">

    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use a function in this particular case.

To achieve your goal, create a view `comments.blade.php`. Depending on your Laravel version and setup you can put it into `app/views` or `resources/views` directory.

The content of this file has to be like follows:

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
<div class="comment">
    <div class="username">{{ $comment->username }}</div>
    <div class="message">{{ $comment->message }}</div>
    <div class="children">
        @include('comments', ['comments' => $comment->children])
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Then render this view and pass the same argument you were passing to your `getComments()` function.

This will hopefully give the desired result.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can send the data to view from function you can use by three method compact,with and session. compact of with method while your are redirecting of loading any view you can use compact or ->with(array());